# PHP Time Execution & Show content in browser when it ready?

Tags: php, time

First of all the script take sometimes to execute and it stops after 30 seconds. Says that the execution time is max about 30 seconds (I know that we can change this param in the httpconf)
but I don't know the max execution time may be 1 hour or more.

So I want to know if there is no time limit execution in php?

Second question: how to show the content in a browser when it's ready and continue the execution, because I always wait the script to end in order to see the content displayed in the browser.

Comment: You should show us some code !

Comment: I have done a research but i did not found ! i use stackoverflow when i'm   blocked !

Comment: here is a script , it did not work !

    <?php
     ob_start();
    
     for($i=0;$i<70;$i++)
     {
         echo 'printing...<br />';
         ob_flush();
         flush();
    
         usleep(300000);
     }

?>

Answer (score 1):

Next time you post a question, make sure to research it better. Both questions are well documented on stackoverflow and the internet.

now to your answer...
To let it run until finished regardless of the time it takes:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

To display content right after it is generated:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A script that might run that long should be run from the console. Browser timeouts could also interfere with running it via browser.
2. If you use a console script, you could route the output into a database and query it from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have in `php.ini` this code. I am not sure you could check it from elsewhere than `php.ini`.

   ```
   ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
   ; http://php.net/max-execution-time
   ; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
   max_execution_time = 30
   ```
2. You can't do that in php. The script runs until it finishes execution (normal, or error).